# Use LINQ To find multiple instances of Min() in Object and change the element(s)

Tags: c#, linq, list

I've the following classes;

```
public class PricePlan
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Price> Prices { get; set; }

    public PricePlan()
    {
        Prices = new List<Price>();
    }
}

public class Price
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public bool Free { get; set; }

    public Price()
    {
        Free = false;
    }
}
```

And then the following to populate the object and list;

```
PricePlan oPricePlan = new PricePlan();

oPricePlan.Name = "Standard Rate Plan";

Price oPrice;
DateTime oDate = DateTime.Today;

for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++)
{
   oPrice = new Price();
   oPrice.Date = oDate.AddDays(x);
   oPrice.Rate = 10 * x;
   oPricePlan.Prices.Add(oPrice);
}

oPrice = new Price();
oPrice.Date = oDate.AddDays(11);
oPrice.Rate = 10;
oPricePlan.Prices.Add(oPrice);
```

The sample data might be:

    `02/01/2013,10,False
    03/01/2013,20,False
    04/01/2013,30,False
    05/01/2013,40,False
    06/01/2013,50,False
    07/01/2013,60,False
    08/01/2013,70,False
    09/01/2013,80,False
    10/01/2013,90,False
    12/01/2013,10,False`

Using

> oPricePlan.Prices.Min(r => r.Rate)

I get get the Min value for the Rate or IndexOf[] can return the first instance.  However, I'm wanting to return X number of lowest rates.  For example how can I set the following;

- For 1 Min rate (two rates might have the same Min) in the system, set it to 0 zero and the Free bool to true
- For 2 Min rates (that might be the same), set it to 0 zero and the Free bool to true

So basically I'm wanting to find the lowest X number of rates, change the actual lowest rates found, and set the Free bool flag to true.

Should I look at using LINQ, or is their a preferred way ?

Comment: Include example output to clarify your question. I came to a different conclusion that another answerer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int numberOfItems = 1;
var orderedPrices = oPricePlan.Prices.OrderBy(x => x.Rate).ToList();
decimal targetRate = orderedPrices[numberOfItems - 1].Rate;
foreach (var price in orderedPrices.TakeWhile(x => x.Rate <= targetRate))
{
    price.Rate = 0;
    price.Free = true;
}
```

**Edit:** The above is based on selecting a `targetRate` based on `numberOfItems`, and then setting all items less than or equal to that to `0` (which might be `numberOfItems` or a little more items). Originally I had:

For your example input, this code will select one of the items with a rate of `10` (it'll be whichever happened to come first in `oPricePlan.Prices` since [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability)). That is, it is the number of *items*, not the number of distinct *rates*. I think that's what you're asking for; otherwise a solution like [Tim Schmelter's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20247015/781792) is right.

```
int numberOfItems = 1;
foreach (var price in oPricePlan.Prices.OrderBy(x => x.Rate).Take(numberOfItems))
{
    price.Rate = 0;
    price.Free = true;
}
```

Comment: In the example the cheapest rates were 10, so I'd want both of them to be set to 0 (on the 02/01/2013 and 12/01/2013).

Comment: Ok, and if you wanted `2` min rates removed instead of `1`, does that mean `10` and `20` or simply both `10`s?

Comment: If I changed numberOfItems, I'd want to take the two lowest rates.  In the example it is 10 and 10.  But could be 10 and 20

Comment: Your original answer seemed to do what I wanted ?

Comment: My original answer would only set *one* of the `10`-rate items to `0`, (since `numberOfItems = 1`) you said you wanted both to be set to `0`.

Comment: But if I changed numberOfItems  to 2 it gets the lowest 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `OrderBy` + `GroupBy`, `Take` and a loop:

```
var priceGroups = oPricePlan.Prices
    .OrderBy(p => p.Rate)  // order by rate ascending
    .GroupBy(p => p.Rate)  // group by rate
    .First()  // use the lowest price-rate group only
    .Take(2); // change 2 to 1 if you only want to modify one price in this min-group

foreach (Price price in priceGroups)
{
    price.Rate = 0;
    price.Free = true;
}
```